# List index out of range when try to close ubuntu notifications

Tags: python, notifications, ubuntu-16.04

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 And I was looking for a form to close ubuntu notificatios. I found the script below but when I run it, I've got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "manage_notifications.py", line 6, in <module>
    ["xrandr"]).decode("utf-8").split() if "+0+0" in s][0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Does anyone know what is wrong? 
**The Script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time

w = int([s.split("x")[0] for s in subprocess.check_output(
    ["xrandr"]).decode("utf-8").split() if "+0+0" in s][0]
        )

def get_mouse():
    loc = subprocess.check_output(["xdotool", "getmouselocation"]).decode("utf-8").split()[:2]
    return [int(n.split(":")[1]) for n in loc]

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    try: 
        subprocess.check_output(["pgrep", "notify-osd"]).decode("utf-8")
        curloc1 = get_mouse(); t = 1
        while t < 10:
            time.sleep(1)
            curloc2 = get_mouse()
            test1 = curloc1[0] > w - 400 and curloc1[1] < 400
            test2 = curloc2[0] > w - 400 and curloc2[1] < 400
            if all([test1 == False, test2 == True]):
                subprocess.Popen(["pkill", "notify-osd"])
                break
            curloc1 = curloc2
            t = t+1
    except:
        pass
```

[output edited]: The output of xrandr:

```
    me@my_pc:$ xrandr
    Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2732 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
    LVDS1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 173mm
       1366x768      59.97*+
       1360x768      59.80    59.96  
       1280x720      60.00  
       1024x768      60.00  
       1024x576      60.00  
       960x540       60.00  
       800x600       60.32    56.25  
       864x486       60.00  
       640x480       59.94  
       720x405       60.00  
       680x384       60.00  
       640x360       60.00  
    DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    VGA1 connected 1366x768+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 410mm x 230mm
       1366x768      59.79*+
       1280x720      60.00  
       1024x768      75.08    75.03    60.00  
       832x624       74.55  
       800x600       75.00    60.32    56.25  
       640x480       75.00    60.00  
       720x400       70.08  
    VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Do I need to change something inside the python script to match my machine configuration?

Comment: Open a terminal and enter `xrandr`. Maybe you don't have installed the package containing this method. Or the output does not contain `"+0+0"`.

Comment: added xrandr output

Comment: Try and comment out the lines `w = int( ... )` and add `w = __import__('Tkinter').Tk().winfo_screenwidth()` instead.